# Using RStudio and Quarto to publish to bookdown and receive any error - prohibited by policy

Tags: r, bookdown, quarto

I regularly publish work to bookdown.org using R Quarto from RStudio.

But today I have an error message when I try to publish which says:
"This type of content is not allowed because it is prohibited by policy."

The document I am trying to publish contains a tmap, some free text, and a scatter plot.  Does anybody have any ideas on this or where the policy is that I could read?  Googling this error hasn't revealed anything and have been publishing happily for a few years now.

Thank you,
Phil,

Comment: The error message almost certainly comes from your company network firewall, and is caused by some HTTP request. You need to figure out *which* request is causing it, and then you probably need to lodge a ticket with your IT department to adjust the firewall rules.